# C# List<> GroupBy 2 Values

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable, group-by

I'm using C# on Framework 3.5. I'm looking to quickly group a Generic List<> by two properties. For the sake of this example lets say I have a List of an Order type with properties of CustomerId, ProductId, and ProductCount. How would I get the sum of ProductCounts grouped by CustomerId and ProductId using a lambda expression?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
var sums = Orders.GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerID, x.ProductID })
                 .Select(group => group.Sum(x => x.ProductCount));
```

Answer (score 17):

I realize this thread is very old but since I just struggled through this syntax I thought I'd post my additional findings - you can return the sum and the IDs (w/o foreach) in one query like so:

```
var sums = Orders
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerID, x.ProductID })
            .Select(group =>new {group.Key, ProductCount = group.Sum(x => x.ProductCount)});
```

The tricky part for me to get it working is that the sum must be aliased, apparently...

Comment: I realize this answer is very old, but if anyone was wondering why the alias is necessary, properties generate implicit field names but methods do not.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you want to get the IDs for each sum, you could do this

```
var customerAndProductGroups =
    from order in Orders
    orderby order.CustomerID, order.ProductID // orderby not necessary, but neater
    group order by new { order.CustomerID, order.ProductID };

foreach (var customerAndProductGroup in customerAndProductGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} has ordered product {1} for a total count of {2}",
        customerAndProductGroup.Key.CustomerID,
        customerAndProductGroup.Key.ProductID,
        customerAndProductGroup.Sum(item => item.ProductCount));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

var New1 = EmpList.GroupBy(z =>  z.Age).OrderBy(Employee => Employee.Key);

dataGridView1.DataSource = New1;

Comment: This answer does not appear to apply to the question.